# Altering already present javascript files server-side with XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

I am currently trying to both work out and investigate the possibility of using 'stored XSS' to manipulate websites javascript files.

So for an example, if a website loaded with a script called 'infinite-scroll.js' and under the assumption that is vulnerable to XSS attacks, would it be possible to add my own code to 'infinite-scoll.js' using XSS? Then store that to the web server so anyone who access that website in the future also would see that script with my altered code?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

An XSS vulnerability is where a server takes user input and then outputs it again without proper escaping causing content which the site designer expected to be treated as text to be treated as executable JavaScript.

A stored vulnerability is one where the input is saved to the server and later output. For example, a comment system might ask for your name, which you could give as `<script>alert('XSS');</script>`, and then that JavaScript would run in the browser of anyone viewing that comment later.

While there *could* be a vulnerability which allows an attacker to overwrite a static JavaScript file with their own version, it wouldn't usually be classed as XSS.

Comment: Ok thank you very much very helpful! For context im attempting to work out how a data breach was conducted where static js was altered, is this a common vulnerability?

Comment: If a file was updated, than that means someone found a hole where they can save files on your system. So my guess is you have a bigger issue at hand. My guess is someone has not kept up with the security updates for whatever frameworks you are using and someone exploited it.

Comment: Thank you very much, making a little more sense now. As far as I can tell, the attacker has used some sort of js injection attack to 'add code' to an already present static js file. They injected this script on one page (that was vulnerable [to something]) which (because they used a global javascript folder) in turn updated all of the sites js files, causing the breach.